# What are some good resources for building a voxel engine?

Tags: voxels

What are some good resources (tutorials, code, papers, etc.) for learning about [voxel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) rendering?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recently did some experimentation with voxels for rendering terrain, with support for overhangs. I pretty much used these articles to build my prototype:

- This [GPU gems 3 chapter](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html) on generating procedural terrain on the GPU. Even though my solution was CPU based (I work with shader model 3, so I couldn't reuse any of their shaders). There's a lot of good information buried in here!
- The Wikipedia entry on [the marching cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) algorithm. Great set of references, such as to [this site that has a good pictorial overview](http://users.polytech.unice.fr/%7Elingrand/MarchingCubes/algo.html) on how things work.
- For any procedural work, you're going to need a good noise library like [Lib noise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/). There are also [C# equivalents for Lib Noise](https://github.com/dhlevi/LibnoiseDesigner).

Something to look out for, I could never get normal generation to work correctly once I had generated a mesh from my voxels. If anyone can give any pointers for this, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 8):

[Here is a 10 year old tutorial](http://www.flipcode.com/voxtut/) that goes pretty deep into Voxel rendering as a technology. It's still a good read.

Comment: This article doesn't exists anymore.

Answer (score 5):

This paper by Jon Olick is pretty interesting:
http://s08.idav.ucdavis.edu/olick-current-and-next-generation-parallelism-in-games.pdf

And those two forum threads about it:
http://ompf.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=904

and:
https://mollyrocket.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=551

It gives you a nice overview about how things could be done in a modern voxel engine.

Comment: 2nd link appears to be what is now a browser addon (possibly malicious) and the 3rd link is dead. Just wanted to warn people before they bother clicking :)

Answer (score 2):

I work on an open-source voxel library called [PolyVox](http://www.volumesoffun.com/polyvox-about/) which has some good documentation for the technology. Also linked at the bottom of our [documentation page](http://www.volumesoffun.com/polyvox-documentation/) is a chapter of 'Game Engine Gems Volume 1' on volumetric representations in games via Google Books.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [Stackoverflow post for links to Voxel libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022123/know-any-voxel-graphics-c-libraries/12583533#12583533).

I'm also developing a [renderer based on voxel raycasting](http://www.forceflow.be/category/phd/).

I developed an out-of-core voxelizer and SVO builder and published paper and code [here](http://graphics.cs.kuleuven.be/publications/BLD13OCCSVO/).